# Another Method To Select All File Types In Python

Tags: python, csv, visual-studio-code, executable, glob

I created a script that runs perfectly fine in visual studio code but I'm now trying to automate that script which is proving to be a little tricky. I've turned the file into a unix  executable file for the automation but when I click on my script, I keep recieving an error. There is a part of the scrip that selects all of the .csv file types and deletes them like so...

```
filestodelete = glob.glob('*.csv')[0]
os.remove('/Users/emmanuel/Documents/Selenium/{}'.format(filestodelete))
```

The issue is that when the terminal reaches this segment of the code, I receive this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emmanuel/Documents/Selenium/OptionsBotCode.py", line 32, in <module>
    filestodelete = glob.glob('*.csv')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I almost think that it's because when I run the code in VSC, the code automatically uses the directory of the folder where the code is located. However, when I'm running it through the exec file, it doesn't know which directory to look for the items it needs to delete, and it's not able to get the directory because it reads this line (with no directory information)

```
filestodelete = glob.glob('*.csv')[0]
```

before it reads this one

```
os.remove('/Users/emmanuel/Documents/Selenium/{}'.format(filestodelete))
```

I've tried to specify to location by placing the targeted directory before the *.csv like this

```
filestodelete = glob.glob('/Users/emmanuel/Documents/Selenium/*.csv')[0]
os.remove('/Users/emmanuel/Documents/Selenium/{}'.format(filestodelete))
```

but I keep getting this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emmanuel/Documents/Selenium/OptionsBotCode.py", line 33, in <module>
    os.remove('/Users/emmanuel/Documents/Selenium/{}'.format(oldfilename))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/emmanuel/Documents/Selenium//Users/emmanuel/Documents/Selenium/CC.csv'
```

besides, I dont think this is the way to do it, I just wanted to have a try.

Does anyone know a workaround this? Maybe a way that I can select and manipulate all of the .csv files in a directory without using glob.glob and confusing my poor computer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print(glob.glob('*.csv'))` will show that you get the index error when the returned list is empty.  `filestodelete = glob.glob('*.csv')[0]` selects one file from the list of files returned, but if there are no files then index 0 is invalid.

Instead use the following, which will run on each file in the returned list and which won't run `os.remove` if the list is empty:

```
for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    os.remove(file)
```

Without a path the above will only look for CSV files in the current directory.
You can put the directory in front as well:

```
for file in glob.glob('/Users/emmanuel/Documents/Selenium/*.csv'):
    os.remove(file)
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. Thank you soo much @MarkTolonen 
The only issue I'm having now is that any subsequent .csv files that are imported into the directory after the new code is run, get deleted. Is there a way to stop the delete process after a couple code lines?
To put things into context, after I delete all of the .csv files in that directory, I then need to import a new .csv file that I can edit and email. Those parts of the code have already been written and work within VSC. They aren’t able to work using the EXEC file as they get deleted before they can be manipulated and emailed.

Comment: I hope that makes sense @Mark